# param is missing or the value is empty: event

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Not exactly sure why the :event param isn't pulling the current event. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

> **EventsController**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :requireLogin

    def requireLogin
        if session[:user_id] == nil
            redirect_to "/"
        end
    end

    def index
       @events = Event.all
    end

   def main
       @event = Event.find(params[:id])
       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
       @creator = User.find(@event.createdByID)
    end

   def new
       @event = Event.new
            @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
       @event.createdByID = @current_user.id
    end

   def coming
       @title = "coming"
       @event = Event.find([:id])
       @events = @event.coming.paginate(page: params[:page])
       render 'show'
    end

    def create
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        @event.createdByID = Rails.application.config.currUserID
        if @event.save
            redirect_to '/event'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
            redirect_to action: "show"
            # Handle a successful update.
            else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to(events_path)
    end

    private
    def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :place, :time_of)
    end
end
```

> **Edit view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="edit-event">
  <div class="container">

    <h2>Tell us about your dog!</h2>
    <div class="edit-area">
        <%= form_for(current_user) do |u| %>
        <div class="field">
            Event Name:
            <%= u.text_field :event_name %>
            Event Place:
            <%= u.text_field :place %>
            <%= u.submit "Submit"%>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean by "pulling the current event" but you need to use `@event` in your form.

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |u| %>
```

--
**up**

remove edit and replace it with this

```
  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event }      
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: After I changed my code to reflect this^, I am still receiving the same error.

ActionController::parameterMissing in EventsController#edit
param is missing or the value is empty :event

in events controller line highlighted:

params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :place, :time_of)

if @event.update_attributes(event_params)

Comment: updated my answer. Plz add this error to your question body.

Comment: Changed the edit method to mirror the code above and added the update method but now there is an issue with the edit view form_for again

Error on event error view
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: Awesome so the Edit form is now displaying with no issues but instead of modifying the already created event, it is adding a new event

Comment: oh, haha. sry. Updated the answer again. Use `form_for(@event)` but update edit meth inside your controller.

Comment: :) not a problem at all. Thanks for the help! We are close I can feel it. There's now a routing issue which is 
No route matches [PATCH] "/event.1" 
clearly it should be event/1
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: add your `routes.rb` to your question. You can just try upading `routes.rb` with `resources :events`

Comment: routes added. little unclear what u mean about updating routes with resources: events -